# How to include calculated column in "New item" in Sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, list-form

I have 2 calculated columns Urgency and Priority which I need to show in New item in SharePoint which will help the users in knowing/understanding them before they submit the request.

Also is there any way I can include a pop up at the time of submission of the request what the priority of the request is?

Answer (score 1):

Calculated columns cannot be shown on list forms using out of the box capabilities.

You need to customize the list form using Power Apps, reproduce the calculated column value logic using Power apps formulas & show the calculated value on list form using label control.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. Also is there a way to show a pop up at the time of submission with priority column(calculated field) to show the user the priority thats populated for the request?

Comment: Yes, you can easily create popup in power apps. For popup, check [this](https://www.spguides.com/powerapps-popup-message-box/) & [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dialog-box-confirmation-box-in-powerapps/)

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way.